# MVC 3 dropdownfor populated but cannot get user's selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, selecteditem, dropdownlistfor

I'm new to MVC 3. I want 3 dropdown lists. The user picks an item from each list and then retrieves the selections based on the matches. For my problem I'm just using 2 dropdowns and code snippets. I have all 3 dropdowns populated - the first two from Linq to Sql and the 3rd is an option list created with Razor (A-Z). 
I'm missing the step of setting the values of what was chosen into MemberSetup.SelectedProgramID and MemberSetup.SelectedOrganizationID. I'd like the text stored in MemberSetup.SelectedProgramName and MemberSetup.SelectedOrganizationName respectively. I think if I can get the selected ids into the model, I can pass them through ActionLink and not deal with @Html.Hidden variables. However, no matter what is selection the model SelectedProgramID and SelectedOrganizationID are zero (expect 1, 2, 3 or 4 for Program ID and 1, 2, 5, or 6 for Organization ID).
Any help / corrections would be appreciated.
Model:

```
{
    public int SelectedProgramID { get; set; }
    public string SelectedProgramName { 
        get { return this._myProgramName; }
        set { this._myProgramName = value; }
    }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProgramList { get; set; }
    public int SelectedOrganizationID { get; set; }
    public string SelectedOrganizationName
    {
        get { return this._myOrganizationName; }
        set { this._myOrganizationName = value; }
    }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OrganizationList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
{
var db = new STARDataContext();
MemberSetup  setupModel = new MemberSetup();
setupModel.ProgramList =  db.ProgramAlls.ToList()
    .Select(p => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = p.ProgramID.ToString(),
        Text =  p.ProgramName.ToString()
    });

setupModel.OrganizationList = db.AreaAlls.ToList()
    .Select(p => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = p.AreaID.ToString(),
        Text = p.AreaName.ToString()
    });
return View(setupModel);
}
```

View:

```
{
@using ( Html.BeginForm() ) {
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProgramID, Model.ProgramList)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedOrganizationID, Model.OrganizationList, "Please select Organization", new { @class = "DropDownList" } )
@Html.Hidden("SelectedProgramID", Model.SelectedProgramID)
@Html.Hidden("SelectedProgramName", Model.SelectedProgramName)
@Html.Hidden("SelectedOrganizationID", Model.SelectedOrganizationID)
@Html.Hidden("SelectedOrganizationName", Model.SelectedOrganizationName)
@Html.ActionLink("Get Members", "Select", new {programID=Model.SelectedProgramID,orgID=Model.SelectedOrganizationID })
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use hiddenFor instead of hidden,so your syntax should look like this

@Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.SelectedProgramName)

Since you have SelectedProgramID and SelectedOrganizationID defined, you won't need to use hidden field for it. To construct the dropdown, you should do something like this

Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.ID,
        new SelectList(Model.Products,"ID", "Sku", Model.ID), " select ")

For your reference: [Use Html.DropDownListFor to get a selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568848/use-html-dropdownlistfor-to-get-a-selected-value)

Comment: I created variables for SelectedProgramID & SelectedOrganizationID. They are not set - always zero. I was expecting the x=>x.ID to fill the variable. I don't know how to capture the seleced value (or text).

Comment: Confused. @Html.HiddenFor gives syntax errors & I don't think I need "hidden". Why create a new list when I have a filled in IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProgramList (in the controller)? PROBLEM: How to set the variables SelectedProgramID & SelectedOrganizationID. Adding [HttpPost] for Index - skipped. Goes to Select & the values of the dropdowns are unknown (set to zero). Something is missing to get the information from the view to the controller.

Comment: Oops, I've just updated the code, there shouldn't be () in the hidden for syntax, since that's a property. Your syntax looks for good to me, can you double check the values of the dropdown been initialised properly, that is check the final html been generated by  and paste it in your question.

Comment: I am very sorry. I don't follow your example.

Comment: I removed Selected*ID, Selected*Name from the class - KISS. Edits to Program crashes. Use Org. DB = AreaAlls [AreaID int, AreaName varchar(20)]. Class OrganizationList above. The dropdown views properly - see my code above. How do I get the selected value from the dropdowns in Controller for Index [HttpPost]?

Answer (score 0):

The above class, controller and view are correct for presenting the drop-downs. This is why I was perplexed.

However, I had the SelectMember in the Get section. [HttpPost] and SelectMember can see what was selected.